# Kotlin - enhanced loop through Custom HashMap (ArrayList<List<E>>)

Tags: kotlin

Notice:
Do not redirect me to a seperate answer that is harder than 'beginner' level. I will not understand it, nor appreciate it.

//named SymmetricalHash because it only takes one generic type, meaning both the `key` and `value` should be of the same data type.

```
class SymmetricalHash<E> {
    private var map: ArrayList<List<E>> = arrayListOf() // just initializing the ArrayList
    fun toStr(): String {
        var mapStr: String = ""
        // this next line is confusing me
        for (elem: List<E> in 0 until map.size) {
            E tempKey=elem[0]
            E tempValue=elem[1]
            mapStr+="{$tempKey, $tempValue}, "
        }
    }
}
```

Errors:
There is a red line under `List<E>` in the for loop condition. It states: "Loop type parameter mismatch: Iterated values: Int, Parameter: List".

**Please explain in simple terms. I am 13 and have little experience with Kotlin/programming**. Thanks :)

For a personal mini-project, I am making a custom HashMap in Kotlin. I have a whole bunch of other functions, like put, get, getKey, and getValue that are all working. However, I wanted to be able to print out the HashMap.

Comment: gdomo's answer explains the specific problem. Once you've sorted that, though, there are design issues you might want to think about. First: using a `List<E>` to store each pair is awkward. Presumably the rest of the code will ensure that each list has exactly two elements? But the compiler can't check that for you, and it's not obvious to anyone else reading the code. Perhaps a `Pair<E, E>` might be more suitable? (It's also likely to take a little less memory.)  (contd…)

Comment: Second: you might want to consider how your class will behave if it has a _lot_ of entries — in particular, how long will it take to look up one key, or set/replace one value, or anything else you're likely to do? I expect it has to scan through every entry in the list until it finds the right one — and so the more entries there are, the slower it gets. So most map implementations don't work that way; they tend to use hashing, or they keep keys in some order and do a binary search; or some other way to locate a specific key more quickly. (contd…)

Comment: Of course, those are more advanced techniques, you can't be expected to know everything when you're just starting! Writing personal projects is a great way to learn, and you always understand something better when you've tried to write it yourself. (And for what it's worth, I myself wrote a map implementation using an ArrayList — for a special case where we knew there would only ever be a few entries, and the memory saving over a standard HashMap was very significant… So your approach is sometimes a good one.)

Comment: I was wondering what other alternative there was for List, that would be better suited in a HashMap. Thank you very much for providing `Pair<E, E>`. It helped lots!

Comment: Happy to help! — Oh, and one other thing worth knowing: it's usually a bad idea to append to a string in a loop. (Again, this is about performance. Strings are immutable, so each time through it has to allocate a new one, copying the existing one — and they get bigger each time, so it'll get _really_ slow for big maps.) A better way is to create a `StringBuilder`, call `append()` on it each time through the loop, and then call `toString()` on it afterward. (Or Kotlin's `buildString` function can do the same with slightly less code.)

Answer (score 0):

With that `for` loop you are iterating from 0 to `map.size`, which is iterating through numbers, more specifically `Int`'s. So you have either declare variable as Int like this:

```
    for (elemIndex: Int in 0 until map.size) {
        val elem = map[elemIndex]
        val tempKey: E = elem[0]
        val tempValue: E = elem[1]
        mapStr+="{$tempKey, $tempValue}, "
    }
```

either (I recommend) use `forEach` like this:

```
    map.forEach { elem ->
        val tempKey: E = elem[0]
        val tempValue: E = elem[1]
        mapStr+="{$tempKey, $tempValue}, "
    }
```